# relation between $W^{1,\infty}$ and $C^{0,1}$

Tags: sobolev-spaces

I know that $f \in C^{0,1}_{loc}(U)\Leftrightarrow f \in W^{1,\infty}_{loc}(U)$ and I have a reference for this. I would like a reference or a explanation for $C^{0,1} = W^{1,\infty}$ on domain convex.

Comment: Did you try to see if the proof of the first equivalence works for the second as well? I'm pretty sure it does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose $f\in C^{0,1}(U)$. Then $f$ is Lipschitz on every segment parallel to coordinates axis (and on other segments, too). Hence, it is absolutely continuous on every segment, with bounded derivative. This qualifies it as a member of $W^{1,\infty}(U)$.

Conversely,  suppose $W^{1,\infty}(U)$. This means that $f$ is absolutely continuous on almost every coordinate-aligned segment, with bounded derivative. That is to say, $f$ is Lipschitz on such segments, with a uniform bound on Lipschitz constant. Let $E$ be the union of these "good" segments. Because $U$ is convex, any two points $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $(y_1,\dots,y_n)$ in $E$ can be connected by a polygonal line contained within $E$ with total length at most 
$$2\sum |x_i-y_i|\le 2\sqrt{n} \|x-y\|$$
Therefore, $f$ is Lipschitz on $E$. Since $U\setminus E$ is a null set, we can redefine $f$ there to make it Lipschitz on $U$ (extending $f$ to $U$ by continuity).

Reference: Theorem 4.1 in [Lectures on Lipschitz Analysis](http://www.math.jyu.fi/research/reports/rep100.pdf) by Heinonen.

See also [Sobolev embedding for $W^{1,\infty}$？](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/269526/)

Comment: +1 for finding 5pm's answer. I remember GT used the exterior cone condition to prove the embedding, it seems quasiconvexity is even weaker. Any reference?

Comment: @ShuhaoCao Theorem 4.1 in [Lectures on Lipschitz Analysis](http://www.math.jyu.fi/research/reports/rep100.pdf). Quasiconvexity appears several times throughout the text.