# How to show that $W^{2,\infty}(B_1)=C^{1,1}(\bar B_1)$?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Suppose that $B_1$ is the open unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$, denote $W^{2,\infty}(B_1)$ be the sobolev spaces and $C^{1,1}(\bar B_1)$ is the Holder spaces. It seems the equality $W^{2,\infty}(B_1)=C^{1,1}(\bar B_1)$ holds at  first glance, but how to move from intuition to a strictly argument?

What's more, I don't know why closed $\bar B_1$ rather than $B_1$?

Another thing: is this some kind of problem suitable for research or just a well known results?

Comment: This is a standard result, you can find the proof in Evan's PDE for  $W^{1, \infty}(\Omega) = C^{0,1}(\Omega)$. (With $C^1$ boundary).

Comment: Yes, I find it. The final question is why when we consider $Du$ (rather than $u$ itself) we need to modify the $\Omega$ to $\bar \Omega$ in $C^{1,1}$?

Comment: Every Lipschitz functions can be defined up to the boundary, so $C^{0, 1}(\Omega)= C^{0,1}(\overline\Omega)$

Answer (score 2):

For first-order space, see [relation between $W^{1,\infty}$ and $C^{0,1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/172647/) and [Sobolev embedding for $W^{1,\infty}$？](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/269526/)

The result for higher orders follows from $W^{1,\infty}=C^{0,1}$ directly - one no longer needs any consideration of the geometry of domains. That is, if for some domain $U$ we have $W^{1,\infty}(U)=C^{0,1}(U)$, then $W^{k,\infty}(U)=C^{k-1,1}(U)$ for all positive integers $k$.

Sketch: take $u\in W^{2,\infty}$. The weak gradient $Du$ is in $W^{1,\infty}$, hence in $C^{0,1}$. When the weak gradient is given by a continuous function, it is the classical gradient. (Because the antiderivative of a continuous function is differentiable.) Hence, $u\in C^{1,1}$.