# Property implying weak differentiability

Tags: derivatives, sobolev-spaces

What property does imply that a function $f \in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$ ($\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$) is weakly differentiable, namely there exists $g \in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$ such that $\int_{\Omega} f\partial_i \phi = - \int_\Omega g\phi$, for all $\phi \in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ and all $i=1,\ldots,n$? Clearly, if $f \in C^1_c(\Omega)$, then it is weakly differentiable, but is there a weaker assumption that will still imply it? Thank you.

Comment: There indeed exists a complete characterization of weakly differentiable functions. In one dimension, they are exactly the *absolutely continuous* ones. In more dimensions, things are more complicated as one should check absolute continuity along every direction. But somebody did it. You can try looking for "APL property" (or something like that - I don't remember exactly) in the book on Sobolev spaces by Giovanni Leoni.

Comment: I found it: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/817440/8157

Comment: By the way - the correct name is "ACL property", not "APL property".

Comment: The characterization if proposed as an exercise in the book written by Gilbarg and Trudinger, Exercise 7.8. If $\Omega$ is a domain, a function $u$ is weakly differentiable if and only if it is equivalent to a function $\bar{u}$ that is absolutely continuous on almost every line segments in $\Omega$ parallel to the coordinate axes and whose partial derivatives are locally integrable in $\Omega$.

Comment: Thank you. That is really interesting. I did not know about the ACL property.

Comment: For future reference, the characterization "weakly differentiable = absolutely continuous" is very misleading, if not wrong. A counterexample is $\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]} $ which is weakly differentiable but clearly not AC.   As @Siminore luckily pointed out (thanks!) it's probably more like "weakly differentiable = its precise representative is absolutely continuous" (correct me if I'm wrong please).