# Determining Lipschitz constant for a special vector field

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let us be given a vector field $v: C \subset \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ that has the special structure given by
$$ 
v(x) = \alpha(x) \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix}
$$
with a scalar field $\alpha: C \to \mathbb R$. We assume also that $C$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb R^n$.

I want to determine a good Lipschitz constant for this vector field, i.e. find $L$ such that
for all $x,y \in C$ we have
$$
\| v(x)-v(y) \| \le L \| x- y\|.
$$
Now due to the very specific structure of the vector field $v$ I immediately had the idea that $L$ could be given 
$$
L = \max_{x \in C} \| \nabla \alpha (x) \|.
$$
Could someone confirm this please? If this turns out to be correct, how would one prove this rigorously? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to relate derivative to Lipschitz constant is to consider restrictions to line segments, and apply the mean value theorem to them. However, this raises the issue of *convexity* of $C$, since in general the line segment will not lie in $C$.

#### Assuming $C$ is convex

Then $L = \max_{x \in C} \| Dv (x) \|$, where $\|\cdot\|$ means the operator norm of the matrix $D v$.  To find $D v$, use the product rule:
$$
D (\alpha(x) x) = (\nabla \alpha(x) )\otimes x +\alpha(x) I  \tag1
$$
where $\otimes $ is the [outer product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product). Then use the triangle inequality: 
$$
\|D (\alpha(x) x)\|\le  \| (\nabla \alpha(x) )\| \|x\| + |\alpha(x)|
$$
and take the supremum over $x\in C$.

#### Assuming $C$ is [quasiconvex](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/269533/147263)

Same as above, but with $L \le M\max_{x \in C} \| Dv (x) \|$ where $M$ is the constant of quasiconvexity.

#### General  $C$

You can pass to the convex hull of $C$, and apply the first part. The supremum of derivative will be taken over the convex hull.