# Lipschitz functions on $\mathbb R^n$ has bounded derivative

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lipschitz-functions

A function $u:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is Lipschitz if and only if $u \in W^{1,\infty}([a,b])$.

Is it also true for $u:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ for $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^n$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Other_examples would suggest otherwise?

Comment: If $\Omega$ is sufficiently nice, it is true. See this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269526/sobolev-embedding-for-w1-infty