# Absolute continuity of a $W^{1,1}(\mathbb{R}^d)$-function along smooth curves

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces, absolute-continuity

My question is related to this one [Is a Sobolev function absolutely continuous with respect to a.e.segment of line?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/908175/is-a-sobolev-function-absolutely-continuous-with-respect-to-a-e-segment-of-line) and its answer, but to my understanding it has not answered the question below.

Let $u \in W^{1,1}(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})$ and $\phi \in C_b^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^d)$. Let $I:= (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ be such that $\text{Id}+t\phi:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}^d$ is invertible for all $t \in I$.

Is $t\mapsto u((\text{Id}+t\phi)^{-1}(x))$ absolutely continuous for $dx$-a.e. $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$?

Under the assumptions on $\phi$, $t\mapsto (\text{Id}+t\phi)^{-1}(x)$ should be a smooth curve for each $x$. However, for $x_1 \neq x_2$, the curves are not expected to be parallel, so to me it seems a result of type "$u$ is absolutely continuous along almost every curve parallel to any given reasonable curve" would not help.

Comment: Such functions might not even be bounded if $d>1$.

Comment: Let us assume in addition that $u$ is bounded.

Comment: Then take an unbounded $W^{1,1}$-function $v$ and consider $u(x):=\sin(v(x))$.