# Verification of extension result for Lipschitz functions

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

does anyone know the following result? If it holds in this form and any source which presents it? Thanks a lot.

Consider metric space $(X,d_{X})$. 
Let $f:A \subset (X,d_{X}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Lipschitz continuous function i.e. $\exists K > 0$ such that 
\begin{align*}
|f(x)-f(y)| \leq Kd_{X}(x,y) ~~~~\forall x,y \in A
\end{align*} 
then define functions

$$\bar{f_{1}}(x) := \sup\lbrace f(y) - Kd_{X}(x,y): y\in A \rbrace ~~ \forall x  \in X$$ and
$$\bar{f_{2}}(x) := \inf\lbrace f(y) + Kd_{X}(x,y): y\in A \rbrace ~~ \forall x  \in X$$
it follows that 
\begin{align*}
\bar{f_{1}}, \bar{f_{2}}: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} 
\end{align*}
are Lipschitz continuous with 
\begin{align*}
|\bar{f_{i}}(x)-\bar{f_{i}}(z)| \leq Kd_{X}(x,z) ~~~\forall x,z \in X \text{ and } \forall  i = 1,2
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
\bar{f_{i}}(x) = f(x) ~~~ \forall x \in A \text{ and } \forall i =1,2
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Take $\epsilon>0$ and choose $y_x\in A$ such that $$\overline{f}_1(x)\ge f(y_x)-Kd_X(x,y_x)\ge \overline{f}_1(x)-\epsilon\tag{1}.$$

It follow from $(1)$ and the definition of $\overline{f}_1$ that $$\overline{f}_1(x)-\overline{f}_1(z)\le f(y_x)-Kd_X(x,y_x)+\epsilon-f(y_x)+Kd_X(z,y_x).\tag{2}$$

We conclude from $(2)$ that $$\overline{f}_1(x)-\overline{f}_1(z)\le Kd_X(x,z)+\epsilon.$$

Once $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we conclude that $\overline{f}_1(x)-\overline{f}_1(z)\le Kd_X(x,z)$. The other inequality is similar, while the fact that $\overline{f}_1$ is a extension of $f$ is trivial. Analogous arguments works also for $\overline{f}_2$. As an reference, take a look in [Kirszbraun theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirszbraun_theorem) and in section 2.10.43. of [Federer's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540606564).

Comment: So then this would be a good result to use for the last part of my proof in [the post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907146/proposed-proof-of-analysis-result), where I extend from Lipschitz continuity almost everywhere to everywhere.

Comment: Yes, you can use this result too. But I think that, only with the extension by coninutiy, you will get a Lipschitz function. Have you tried to prove it?

Comment: But this result gives a Lipschitz continuous extension on the domain everywhere, that's exactly what I want. What exactly do you mean by "extension by continuity", do you mean by defining the extension to be $f(a) = \lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)$ for all $a \in \partial I$? I haven't tried that extension since I thought this one to be sufficient. What do you think?

Comment: I think that extension by continuity is more fast to state and more easy to prove.

Comment: Could you give a small hint as to how you would approach this proof(just a hint), it doesn't seem that you can simply use an inequality argument with the limits.

Comment: Let $\overline{f}$ be the extension by continuity and let $x,y\in\partial A$. Let $x_n,y_n\in A$ with $x_n,y_n\to x,y$. We have that $$|\overline{f}(x_n)-\overline{f}(y_n)|=|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|\le Kd_X(x_n,y_n),\ \forall\ n$$ Once $\overline{f}$ is continuous, it is suffice to take limit in the above inequality.

Comment: Hi, could I ask your opinion on something. Do you think that [in the paper](http://caa.epfl.ch/publications/9-Boccardo-Dacorogna1984.pdf). On the second page of the paper it says "$V=W^{1,p}$, $p>1$ ($V' = W^{-1,p'})$ with $p' = \frac{p}{p-1}$". Do you think this is a typo? Shouldn't it be $V = W^{1,p}_{0}$. Thanks, sorry to bother.