# if $f :\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Lipschitz continuous function then $f \in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, sobolev-spaces, solution-verification

Let $\Omega = (0, 1) \times (0, 1) \subset \mathbb{R^2}$ and let $f :\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Lipschitz continuous function. Prove that $f \in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$.

**My attempt**:

let $\epsilon>0$ , $\Omega_\epsilon = \{x\in \Omega : B_\epsilon(x)\subset \Omega\}$, and $f_\epsilon= J_\epsilon\ast f$ be the mollification. Then $f_\epsilon \in C^\infty(\Omega_\epsilon)$. We can approximate;

\begin{align}
\|f_\epsilon\|_{ W^{1,\infty}(\Omega_\epsilon)} \le \|D(J_\epsilon\ast f)\|_{ L^{\infty}(\Omega_\epsilon)} \le \|Df\|_{ L^{\infty}(\Omega_\epsilon)} \le \|f\|_{C^1(\Omega_\epsilon)}< \infty 
\end{align}

letting $\epsilon \to 0 $, we have that  $f_\epsilon \to f$ unifromly in $ W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172647/relation-between-w1-infty-and-c0-1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/874982/relation-between-sobolev-space-w1-infty-and-the-lipschitz-class).